# Convert ARM template parameter of type Array to use in Powershell of type String[]

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Objective here is to create an inbound rule in windows firewall, to add multiple remote addresses taken from the template parameter, using a single powershell command.

I have a parameter `vnAddressPrefixes` of type Array which contains Address Prefixes (as given in below default value).

```
"parameters": {
// ... Some more fields not relevant to this question
    "vnAddressPrefixes": {
        "defaultValue": [ "10.0.0.0/16", "10.0.0.0/24" ],
        "type": "Array"
    }
}
```

I have a custom script extension (as given below) which runs a powershell command to **create an inbound rule in windows firewall, to add multiple remote addresses**.

```
"resources": [
    {
        // ... Some more fields not relevant to this question
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "properties": {
            // ... Some more fields not relevant to this question
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
            "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
            "protectedSettings": {
                "commandToExecute": "[variables('commandToExecuteInVm')]"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The variable `commandToExecuteInVm` is constructed from the parameter `vnAddressPrefixes` as given below.
(I am trying to convert the array value from `[10.0.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/24]` to `@("10.0.0.0/16","10.0.0.0/24")`

```
"variables": {
    // Variable for converting array to powershell format. Eg.: [10.0.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/24] to @("10.0.0.0/16","10.0.0.0/24")
    "addressPrefixesTemp1": "[string(parameters('vnAddressPrefixes'))]", // Convert to string
    "addressPrefixesTemp2": "[replace(variables('addressPrefixesTemp1'), '[', '@(\"')]", // Convert [ to @("
    "addressPrefixesTemp3": "[replace(variables('addressPrefixesTemp2'), ',', '\", \"')]", // Convert , to ", "
    "addressPrefixesTemp4": "[replace(variables('addressPrefixesTemp3'), ']', '\")')]", // Convert ] to ")
    // Variable for adding an inbound rule in windows firewall, for specific port, for accessing using application gateway fqdn
    "addFirewallInboundRuleAllow8088": "[concat('New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName Allow_Port_8088 -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 8088 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -RemoteAddress ', variables('addressPrefixesTemp4'), ' ; ')]",

    // Variable to store the final command to be executed in the VM
    "commandToExecuteInVm": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted ', variables('addFirewallInboundRuleAllow8088'))]"
}
```

I am getting the below error which mentions that the value provided for `RemoteAddress` is invalid.

> Command execution finished, but failed because it returned a non-zero
> exit code of: '1'. The command had an error output of:
> 'New-NetFirewallRule : The address is invalid. Addresses may be
> specified as IP addresses, ranges, or subnets. Also, the following
> address keywords are allowed in certain places: LocalSubnet, DNS,
> DHCP, WINS, DefaultGateway, Internet, Intranet, Intran...' For more
> information, check the instance view by executing Get-AzVmssVm or
> Get-AzVm (https://aka.ms/GetAzVm). These commands can be executed
> using CloudShell (https://aka.ms/CloudShell)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like powershell expects the double quotes to be escaped.
So, the array value should be converted from `[10.0.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/24]` to `@(\"10.0.0.0/16\",\"10.0.0.0/24\")`. (Notice that the double quotes is escaped).

Which means, a backslash (which should also be escaped) had to be added before the escaped double quote.

So, `\"` will become `\\\"`.

```
"variables": {
    // Variable for converting array to powershell format. Eg.: [10.0.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/24] to @(\"10.0.0.0/16\",\"10.0.0.0/24\")
    "addressPrefixesTemp1": "[string(parameters('vnAddressPrefixes'))]", // Convert to string
    "addressPrefixesTemp2": "[replace(variables('addressPrefixesTemp1'), '[', '@(\\\"')]", // Convert [ to @(\"
    "addressPrefixesTemp3": "[replace(variables('addressPrefixesTemp2'), ',', '\\\", \\\"')]", // Convert , to \", \"
    "addressPrefixesTemp4": "[replace(variables('addressPrefixesTemp3'), ']', '\\\")')]", // Convert ] to \")
}
```

Let me know if there is any other better way of converting `ARM template` parameter of type `Array` to use in `Powershell` command of type `String[]`, without having to use these many string manipulations.